# How to add class on different if statement in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to change to color of my element each time it clicks the element, (to show start, in-progress and finished). For this I made a variable and increasing its value each time user clicks it and then applying different classes for styling.
***`<div v-for="error in errors" :key="error" class="element" > <span @click="modify()"> {{error}}</span></div>`***
I declare a variable step in data

---

```
modify () {
    step = step + 1
}
```

---

now I want to change styling base of this step (1, 2, 3).
Any idea, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
<div class="element" v-for="error in errors" :key="error" :class="step==1 ? 'class1' : 
  step==2 ? 'class2':'class3'">
  ....
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an approach like this:

```
<div v-for="error in errors" :key="error" :class="`class_${step}`" >
  <span @click="modify()"> {{error}}</span>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to name your classes that way:

```
<div v-for="error in errors" :key="error" :class="getClass" >
  <span @click="modify()"> {{error}}</span>
</div>
...
methods: {
  getClass() {
    if (this.step === 1) return 'classA';
    if (this.step === 2) return 'classB';
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried this way,
'<div v-for="error in errors" :key="error"  class="element"> <span :class="getClass" @click="modify()"> {{error}} </span>   </div>
    </div>'


'getClass () {
    console.log(this.step)
    if(this.step === 1){
     return 'element1'
    }
    if(this.step == 2){
     return 'element2'
    }
    else return 'element3'
   },
    modify () {
     this.step = this.step + 1
     console.log(this.step)
    }'
But it's not working.

Comment: you can try moving the getClass function from methods to computed